# For any starting point $x^{(0)}$ the basic conjugate algorithm converges to the unique $x^{*}$ in $n$ steps

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, proof-explanation, gradient-descent

## Proof

[image]
[image]

---

I would like to check my understanding about the above.

## Thoughts

So for this we would have $Q,x^{(0)},b$ and we're trying to find $x^{(*)}$.

The set of Q-conjugate vectors $d^{(i)}, \; i \in 1, 2, \cdots , n-1$ form a
basis, therefore we can express the difference between the optimal point $x^*$
and the starting point $x^{(0)}$ in terms of this basis $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\beta_i
d^{(i)}$.

Using that for Q-conjugate vectors $d^{(i)}, d^{(j)}$ where $i \neq j$ we have
$d^{(i)T}Qd^{(j)} = 0$, the product simplifies and we can factor to get things
in terms of $\beta_k$.

The $\beta$ terms can be expressed in terms of $g^{(0)}$, but we want to express
them in terms of $g^{(k)}$ so that we can use the expression in each step.

Writing $x^{(k)} - x^{(0)}$ in terms of of the basis `(Question 1)` vectors multiplied
by $\alpha$ terms enables us to do that.

Then rearranging shows that $\beta_k = \alpha_k$ `(Question 2)`

## question 1

there seems to be more $\beta$ terms than $\alpha$. There seems to be $1 ,
\cdots , k$ coefficients for $\beta$ and $1 , \cdots , k - 1$ for $\alpha$.

Why is this? If so - how can we equate them? If not (and there are the same
number of each), what am I missing?

## question 2

Why does this complete the proof? Is this showing that we have $k$ coefficients,
and that we can solve for a coefficient with each step. Once we have completed
all steps we're able to express the optimal point $x^{(*)}$ in terms of the
Q-conjugate vectors?

---

This is `Theorem 10.1` from Chong and Zak *"An Introduction to Optimization"*

## edit - confusion about number of coefficients.

From reading the above (to me) it appeared that, if the $\beta$ coefficients
range from $ 1, ... , n-1$, and the $\alpha$ range through $1,...,k-1$.

It's previously stated in the line *"Now premultiply both sides of the ...."*
that $0\leq k < n$.

Then if I can go upto $k$ for $\beta$ coefficients and $k-1$ in $\alpha$ it
seems (to me) that there is one less $\alpha$ coefficient than $\beta$.

Hopefully that explains the confusion that I had wrt to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the algorithm produces $\alpha_0,...,\alpha_{n-1}$ (and $d_0,...,d_{n-1}$), so there
are $n$ of them.

After the last iteration we have $x_n = x_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha_k d_k$.

Since the $d_k$ are linearly independent ($Q$ is symmetric positive definite, I presume) we 
can write the (unique) solution $x_*$ to $Qx_*=b$ as
$x_*=x_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\beta_k d_k$ (in fact, any $x$ can be written this way for
suitable coefficients).

The theorem shows that $\beta_k = \alpha_k$, hence we have
$x_* = x_n$.

Note that the above is a theoretical result, in practice numerical errors accumulate; one can restart to reduce the impact. GC algorithms and their ilk are often used for
finding quick approximate solutions.

Comment: Thanks. "*This theorem shows that ...*", could you clarify why it must be the
case that $x_* = x_n$ under this condition? My reasoning for there being $n$
steps is that there are $n$ coefficients to solve for and every coefficient
takes one step. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The algorithm produces $\alpha_k$.  If we write the solution using the $\beta_k$ as above (which has nothing to do with the algorithm), the theorem proves that $\beta_k = \alpha_k$. Hence we have $x_*-x_0 = x_n-x_0$ and so $x_*=x_n$.

Comment: "*I am not sure what you are asking*", OK that's fine. I'm probably explaining that part poorly, perhaps going through a few examples will clear it up a bit. Thanks.

Comment: If you can clarify what bothers you I will try to address it. Just remember the above is a fairly opaque proof, there are nicer (but more work is involved) ways of showing the same result.

Comment: The nicer result is that the $x_k$ gives the best (in some special sense) approximation to the solution to $Qx=b$ on the space $x_0+ \operatorname{sp} \{ d_0, Q d_0, ,..., Q^{k-1} d_0 \}$. I think it is rather a beautiful result.

Comment: I've added to the original post (only the edit is new). If that edit isn't clear
then don't worry about it. If you have a proof of this in mind that you prefer
perhaps it would be interesting to link it. Thanks though.

Comment: $k $ ranges from $0$ to $n-1$ giving $n$ values.